# jQueryまたはJSまたはcss3のanimationで滑らかに移動させるには？

Tags: javascript, jquery

class="n2"からclass="n1"に移動する際、滑らかにスーッと移動させたいのですが、うまくいきません。
今は、かくかくしています。
jsでclassを変更してcssのpositionで位置をズラしているのですが、滑らかに移動（変更）させるには、どこにどのように書いたらよいでしょうか。ご教示の程よろしくお願いいたします。

https://jsfiddle.net/Lennxhjc/1/

```js
$(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
  var classNameList = [
    'n5', 'n4', 'n3', 'n2', 'n1',
    /*'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'n9'*/
  ];
  setInterval(function() {
    var nodes = classNameList.map(function(className) {
      return {
        className: className,
        $node: $wrapper.find('.' + className)
      };
    });
    var nodes3 = new Array(classNameList.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < classNameList.length; i++) {

      var name = classNameList[i];
      nodes3[i] = {
        $node: $wrapper.find('.' + name),
        className: name
      }
    }
    nodes.forEach(function(current, currentIndex, whole) {
      var nextIndex = (currentIndex === whole.length - 1) ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
      current.$node.removeClass(current.className);
      current.$node.addClass(whole[nextIndex].className);
    });
  }, 5000);
})();
```

```css
#slide {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#slide ul {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

#slide li {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FFF;
}

#slide .n1 {
  /* アニメーション前はn2と同じ大きさ・位置にしておく */
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
}

#slide .n2 {
  bottom: 18%;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 1;
}

#slide .n3 {
  bottom: 30%;
  z-index: 8;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#slide .n4 {
  bottom: 40%;
  z-index: 7;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#slide .n5 {
  bottom: 50%;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#slide .n1 img {
  width: 100%;
}

#slide .n2 img {
  width: 83%;
}

#slide .n3 img {
  width: 73%;
}

#slide .n4 img {
  width: 63%;
}

#slide .n5 img {
  width: 53%;
}


/* img仮の設定 */

img {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
}


/* 3秒止めてから2秒かけてscaleoutのkeyframesを実行（足して5秒）。jsの5秒と同じ。 */

.n1 {
  -webkit-animation: scaleout 2.0s ease-in-out 3.0s;
  animation: scaleout 2.0s ease-in-out 3.0s;
}


/* n1を1.5倍に拡大して消す */

@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide">
  <ul class="wrapper">
    <li class="n1">
      <img src="img/01.jpg" width="" height="" alt="">
    </li>

    <li class="n2">
      <img src="img/02.jpg" width="" height="" alt="">
    </li>

    <li class="n3">
      <img src="img/03.jpg" width="" height="" alt="">
    </li>

    <li class="n4">
      <img src="img/04.jpg" width="" height="" alt="">
    </li>

    <li class="n5">
      <img src="img/05.jpg" width="" height="" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

cssのanimationなら、transformを変化させると滑らかです。
z軸の移動をさせれば、重なり順もちゃんとシミュレートされます。
ループする仕組みもjsより簡素・安全に書けるのでおすすめです。

```css
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
   position: relative;
   width: 200px;
   margin: 1em auto;
   list-style: none;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
   perspective: 500px;
}
.wrapper li {
   background-color: rgba(100,200,100,1);
   color: #fff;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 2;
   transform-origin: center top 0px;
   animation: maenideru 30s infinite both;
}
.wrapper li:nth-of-type(1) {
   animation-delay: -24s;
}
.wrapper li:nth-of-type(2) {
   animation-delay: -18s;
}
.wrapper li:nth-of-type(3) {
   animation-delay: -12s;
}
.wrapper li:nth-of-type(4) {
   animation-delay: -6s;
}
.wrapper li:nth-of-type(5) {
   animation-delay: 0s;
}
@keyframes maenideru {
   0%,10% {
     transform: translateZ(-250px);
     opacity: 0;
   }
   15%,30% {
     transform: translateZ(-200px) translateY(1em);
   }
   35%,50% {
     transform: translateZ(-150px) translateY(2em);
   }
   55%,70% {
     transform: translateZ(-100px) translateY(3em);
   }
   75%,90% {
     transform: translateZ(-50px) translateY(4em);
   }
   95% {
     transform: translateZ(0px) translateY(5em);
     opacity: 1;
   }
   100% {
     transform: translateZ(100px) translateY(4em);
     opacity: 0;
   }
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li>イメージ1</li>
  <li>イメージ2</li>
  <li>イメージ3</li>
  <li>イメージ4</li>
  <li>イメージ5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

アニメーションしながらクラスを変更するのは難しそうな気がしたので、ちょっと違う感じでやってみました。
CSSの設定値をjavascriptにも書かないといけないので良い処理とは言えないかも知れませんが、参考になれば幸いです。

```js
$(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
  var idList = [
    '#n1', '#n5', '#n4', '#n3', '#n2'
  ];
  var indexArray = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
  var attrIndex = 0;
  var attrList = [
    {
      bottom: 0,
      'z-index': 10,
      opacity: 1
    },
    {
      bottom: '18%',
      'z-index': 9,
      opacity: 1
    },
    {
      bottom: '30%',
      'z-index': 8,
      opacity: 0.9
    },
    {
      bottom: '40%',
      'z-index': 7,
      opacity: 0.7
    },
    {
      bottom: '50%',
      'z-index': 6,
      //opacity: 0.4
    }
  ];
  var childAttrList = [
    {width: '100%'},
    {width: '83%'},
    {width: '73%'},
    {width: '63%'},
    {width: '53%'}
  ];

  // webkitAnimationEndを使用する例
  var move = function() {
    var aIndex = attrIndex;
    attrIndex = (attrIndex === idList.length - 1) ? 0 : attrIndex + 1;
    var nodes = idList.map(function(id) {
      return {
        $node: $wrapper.find(id)
      };
    });
    nodes.forEach(function(current, currentIndex, whole) {
      var index = indexArray[aIndex];
      // 移動中は見えなくする場合はこの辺で調整する
      if (index === 4) current.$node.css({opacity:0});
      $('img', current.$node).animate(childAttrList[index], 1000);
      current.$node.animate(attrList[index], 1000, function() {
        // 移動中は見えなくする場合はこの辺で調整する
        if (index === 4) current.$node.animate({opacity:0.4}, 500);
        current.$node.removeClass('animate');
        if (index === 0) {
          animate(current.$node);
        }
      });
      aIndex = (aIndex === whole.length - 1) ? 0 : aIndex + 1;
    });
  }
  var animate = function(obj) {
    obj.one('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function () {
      move();
    });
    obj.addClass('animate');
  }
  // 最初の1回を実行
  animate($('#n1'));
/*  
    // setIntervalを使用する例
    var move = function(isFirst) {
    var aIndex = attrIndex;
    attrIndex = (attrIndex === idList.length - 1) ? 0 : attrIndex + 1;
    var nodes = idList.map(function(id) {
      return {
        $node: $wrapper.find(id)
      };
    });
    nodes.forEach(function(current, currentIndex, whole) {
      var index = indexArray[aIndex];
      // 移動中は見えなくする場合はこの辺で調整する
      if (!isFirst && index === 4) current.$node.css({opacity:0});
      $('img', current.$node).animate(childAttrList[index], 1000);
      current.$node.animate(attrList[index], 1000, function() {
        // 移動中は見えなくする場合はこの辺で調整する
        if (!isFirst && index === 4) current.$node.animate({opacity:0.4}, 500);
        current.$node.removeClass('animate');
        if (index === 0) {
          current.$node.addClass('animate');
        }
      });
      aIndex = (aIndex === whole.length - 1) ? 0 : aIndex + 1;
    });
  }
  // 待ち時間が長いので最初の1回を実行
  move(true);
  setInterval(function() { move(false) }, 5100);
*/
});
```

```css
#slide {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#slide ul {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#slide li {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}
#slide #n1 {
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
}
#slide #n1 img {
  width: 100%;
}
#slide #n2 {
  bottom: 18%;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 1;
}
#slide #n2 img {
  width: 83%;
}
#slide #n3 {
  bottom: 30%;
  z-index: 8;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
#slide #n3 img {
  width: 73%;
}
#slide #n4 {
  bottom: 40%;
  z-index: 7;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#slide #n4 img {
  width: 63%;
}
#slide #n5 {
  bottom: 50%;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
#slide #n5 img {
  width: 53%;
}
img {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
}
/* 3秒止めてから2秒かけてscaleoutのkeyframesを実行（足して5秒）。jsの5秒と同じ。 */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: scaleout 2s ease-in-out 3s;
  animation: scaleout 2s ease-in-out 3s;
}
/* n1を1.5倍に拡大して消す */
@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slide">
  <ul class="wrapper">
    <li id="n1"><img src="" alt="イメージ1"/></li>
    <li id="n2"><img src="" alt="イメージ2"/></li>
    <li id="n3"><img src="" alt="イメージ3"/></li>
    <li id="n4"><img src="" alt="イメージ4"/></li>
    <li id="n5"><img src="" alt="イメージ5"/></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ita_3yさま
ありがとうございます。可愛い猫にも癒されました。奥の画像が一瞬手前にきますが、ゆっくりコードを見て勉強させていただきたいと思います。取り急ぎ、お忙しい中感謝したします。

Comment: @kapimako 少しだけ変更しました。

Comment: @kapimako 昨日から気になっていた点があったので少し変更してみました（setIntervalではなく、webkitAnimationEndを使用するようにしました）。

Comment: @ita_3yさま、確認が遅くなってすみません。すごいです！！css3 animationとjsを連動させているんですね。それによってスムーズな移動が可能になるんですね。setIntervalではなく、webkitAnimationEndを使用された理由は何でしょうか？時間ではなく、animationが終わったタイミングの方が正しい動きをする？という事でしょうか？

Comment: @kapimako うまくタイミングを調整してあげればsetIntervalでも動きに大きな違いは無いと思います。ただ、cssのanimation終了をトリガーにするとちょっとスケールアウトの時間を変えたい時など、cssだけの修正で済むので変更に強いです（setIntervalだとcss, jsそれぞれで時間を管理するため両方のタイミングを合わせないといけない）。一方でcssのanimationの途中にjsで処理を挟みたいとかであれば、setIntervalを使った方が良いかもしれません。試しにcssの秒数を変更してsetIntervalとwebkitAnimationEndの違いを見てみると面白いかもしれません。

Answer (score -1):

この辺のライブラリを使われると簡単だと思います。
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/